# TextView space taken removed if no text from string - Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, textview

Is it possible so if there is no text provided to the TextView the area occupied by the textView in the layout is removed so there is no blank areas where text should be so it can be used by something else.

[image]

Here you can see a gap where information would be under the "17th September 2013" but If I wanted to have that space removed so the layout looked much better but still had the TextView available for other sections as the layout how would it be done. The layout you see above is part of a ListView and so if I just removed the TextView, if there was information under the date part it would not show. The information is being received from an XML file hosted on the internet. Sorry If I explained this very badly.

Online hosted XML file:

```
<games_list>
<game>
<id>1</id>
<title>Grand Theft Auto 5</title>
<date1>17th September 2013</date1>
<date2/>
<date3/>
<platforms>360, PS3</platforms>
<thumb_url>
http://launchpadsoftware.webs.com/ReleaseDates%20Web%20Data/gta5thumb.jpg
</thumb_url>
</game>
<game>
<id>2</id>
<title>Grand Theft Auto 5</title>
<date1>17th September 2013</date1>
<date2/>
<date3/>
<platforms>360, PS3</platforms>
<thumb_url>
http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/eminem.png
</thumb_url>
</game>
</games_list>
```

list_row.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background_card"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:src="@drawable/gta5thumb"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>





<!-- Title Of Song-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/list_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_image"
    android:text="Grand Theft Auto 5"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Artist Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:text="17th September 2013" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/date1"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_image"
    android:text="17th September 2013" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:text="17th September 2013"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"/>

<!-- Rightend Duration -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/platforms"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="360, PS3"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <!-- Rightend Arrow -->    
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom list adapter you should hide the textviews that have no text

textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

and in xml you should use

android:layout_centerVertical="true"

for the textviews that have text.

Comment: But it is part of a ListView so if I hide that TextView, the other sections which will be added later will not be visible. Would it be possible to tell it to either be visible or gone from a XML file on the internet? I have added the layout of the online XML file to my question.

Comment: post also the code of the custom row layout that you're using in the listview.

Comment: I have added the custom row layout that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you will do it dynamically, so you acn do it in code, simply set visibility to gone

```
textView.setVisible(View.GONE);
```

Comment: could I set this via an adapter. For example in my adapter I use this date2.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2)); to set the text of each TextView so could I use the XML file to designate whether it should be hidden or not?

Comment: in your adapter you can use also, but put an if statement before this so you can check whether you want to display next textview or not